# Adding a toolbar causes recyclerview to have a whitespace at bottom (AppBarLayout)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout with relativelayout(my hiding-on-scroll content) and Toolbar which includes layout(my pinned item). To show some items I'm using RecyclerView( GridLayoutManager on it) and items which are shown in RecyclerView are CardView(with linearlayout) items.

Problem is that whitespace appears at bottom of RecyclerView when i have my toolbar, and if i delete toolbar whitespace also dissappear. Problem looks like [this](http://prntscr.com/ifafuf) on device, and it looks normal [in editor](http://prntscr.com/ifb6be).

I tried changing both,cardview and recyclerview height and width but nothing helped.

My xml code for cardview which is used for items in recyclerview:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/white_background_rounded_corners"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/white_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCategory"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/category"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/android_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCategoryName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textColor="@color/mainColour"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

And this is my xml code for whole form(form where recyclerview is used):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/GrayColour"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


                <include
                    android:id="@+id/Header"
                    layout="@layout/header_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/TopBar"
                    layout="@layout/top_navigation_bar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/Categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Also here is my adapter for filling recyclerview with items:

```
    public class Adapter extends FirestoreAdapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "Adapter";

    public CategoryAdapter(Query query) {
        super(query);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new Adapter.ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false));

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(getSnapshot(position).toObject(Category.class));
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.ivCategory)
        ImageView ivCategory;

        @BindView(R.id.tvCategoryName)
        TextView tvCategoryName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        public void bind(final Category category) {
            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

            StorageReference imageRef = storageReference.child(category.getImage());

            Glide.with(ivCategory)
                    .load(imageRef)
                    .into(ivCategory);

            tvCategoryName.setText(category.getName());

            ivCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "test");
                    SecondActivity.start(v.getContext(), category.getName());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Shot in the dark: what if you change your recyclerview's height to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`?

Comment: Still same problem, now i also noticed that whitespace is same dimensions like toolbar,but still dont know what problem is.

Comment: Any solution for this @JohnDoe